# C++ while loop question Codecademy reference [RESOLVED]

Tags: c++

**My queries has been resolved..Thankyou everyone who took the time and explained it to me.**

I am learning C++ from codecademy and this particular snippet is beyond understanding.

```
    #include <iostream>

int main() {

  int pin = 0;
  int tries = 0;

  std::cout << "BANK OF CODECADEMY\n";

  std::cout << "Enter your PIN: ";
  std::cin >> pin;

  while (pin != 1234 && tries <= 3) {

    std::cout << "Enter your PIN: ";
    std::cin >> pin;
    tries++;

  }



    if (pin == 1234) {

        std::cout << "PIN accepted!\n";
        std::cout << "You now have access.\n

"; 

  }

}
```

now m unable to understand that why am I getting 5 tries when i run it on codecamdey.
After some further digging i found out that :

```
while (pin != 1234 && tries != 3
while (pin != 1234 && tries < 3
```

Work as intended, But

```
while (pin != 1234 && tries <= 3)
```

does not... How is this this diffrent from the two i posted above?

Comment: I'm getting 5 tries on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/InnocentDodgerblueTree).

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::cout << "Enter your PIN: ";
 std::cin >> pin;
```

these two lines above while loop is the 5th time exactly . because your loop is running exactly 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping from 0 to <= 3 which means you are looping through 0 1 2 3 which is 4 loops. You need to either start from 1 or change the condition to < 3

Answer (score 0):

This code should loop 5 times. I'll count the times it runs here:

1. The code first runs before the while loop is reached.
2. i is now initialized to 0. The while loop runs.
3. i is increased to one. The while loop runs.
4. i is increased to two. The while loop runs.
5. i is increased to three. The while loop runs.

Now, i is increased to 4. 4 is not less than or equal to three, so the code does not run the while loop.

As you can see, the code runs 5 times. I do not know what happened to the repl.it compiler.